# Can I use AWS for downloading, storing and computing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

There is a project of mine, which demands about 1.2 TB of data to be downloaded from the Internet, and running of scripts over it, in order to convert it to some other end result. So, I can see three problems here:

1. **The downloading:** I can't download this amount of data from my laptop, because of the low downloading rate.
2. **The storage:** The downloaded files must be stored somewhere. Again my laptop doesn't have enough memory to do just that( given that it might be able to download the files magically)
3. **The processing:** Once downloaded and stored, I need to run scripts over the files in order to get the end result. Given the enormous size of the input, this can't be done by my laptop, in a sane amount of time.

Therefore, I only see [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) as an option. I've looked into some of the products offered by them, and from the surface it seems like the processing part can be done by the product called *EC2* (Elastic cloud computing), and the storage can be done by the product called *S3*, scalable storage.

I couldn't find anything meeting my *downloading* demands.

So, can I use the above solution to also download the data?

Comment: This question seems a little bit broad (I removed the too open-ended questions), but I guess you mean the *processing* can be done via EC2 instances (not the storage)? Since EC2 instances are “normal” servers running some OS, you should use these to run a script that downloads the data into an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EC2 instances are basically regular servers that run an operating system, which not only allows you to perform the data processing tasks, but also any other step like downloading, especially if the downloading is a complex task.

You would configure an EC2 instance that permanently mounts an [S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) into the operating system, then create a script (e.g. a shell script) that regularly or semi-regularly downloads the data and stores it in the bucket.

An even simpler option would be to use [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_IL&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=lambda_b&sc_content=lambda_e&sc_detail=aws%20lambda&sc_category=lambda&sc_segment=161190413995&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=IL&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!161190413995!e!!g!!aws%20lambda&ef_id=V9aMuwAAAeOqh4Co:20170307131409:s) to perform the download into S3 without having to spin up an EC2 server, which means you can do the processing independently, and also avoid having to transfer data to the server first, and then onto S3.

Note that any data operation will have a certain price, so make sure to read about the EC2 and S3 pricing policies and [calculate the tentative costs](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).

Comment: As for using an EC2 instance to load data into S3, see [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5589/downloading-a-large-dataset-on-the-web-directly-into-aws-s3) for an example.